# How to perform a part of text search in mongoose array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a schema where I need to perform a search in array of objects. I have tried many ways but it doesn't seems to work. Below is my code.

```
let productsSchema = new mongooseSchema({
    productId: {type: mongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'},
    mainAttributes: [{
        subCategoryId: {type: mongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CategorySubCategory'},
        attributes: Object
    }],
    createdAt: Date,
    updatedAt: Date
})

productsSchema.index({'mainAttributes': 'text'})

let attributes = mongoose.model('Attributes', productsSchema); 

let results = await CategorySubCategory.attributes.find({"$text": {"$search": req.body.searchText}})
```

Currently below record is saved in mongodb

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bba1b39ad9387431f9f5fd9"),
    "productId" : ObjectId("5bba1b397d90713320c441f8"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-10-07T14:42:01.723Z"),
    "mainAttributes" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bba1b397d90713320c441f9"),
            "subCategoryId" : ObjectId("5bba1b397d90713320c441f7"),
            "attributes" : {
                "title" : {
                    "text" : "some title",
                    "type" : "text"
                }
                "state" : {
                    "text" : "California",
                    "type" : "text"
                },
                "city" : {
                    "text" : "San Francisco",
                    "type" : "text"
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5bba1b397d90713320c441fb"),
            "subCategoryId" : ObjectId("5bba1b397d90713320c441fa"),
            "attributes" : {
                "temprature" : {
                    "degree" : "20C",
                    "type" : "text"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-10-07T14:42:01.723Z")
}
```

I need to perform a search on the basis of text, e.g. when I give San, it should return me the result, but it returns empty.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out what was the problem,

I need to explicitly remove an index, and then added

`productsSchema.index({'$**': 'text'})` to make it work